# Getting IllegalStateException while launching Firefox 46.0.1 using Selenium 3.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have Selenium version 3.0.1 and Firefox version 46.0.1.
In selenium 3.0.1 [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG) it is mentioned that:

> Geckodriver is now the default mechanism for automating Firefox. This
>      is Mozilla's implementation of a driver for that browser, and is
>      required for automating Firefox versions 48 and above

Although I am getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

while executing the below code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Why am I getting this error nevertheless I am using Firefox version < 48.0 ?
Is it mandatory to use Geckodriver with Selenium 3.0.1 ?

Above code is working perfectly if I make following changes:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path to geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 2):

you **have to** set the following property for all Firefox browsers irrespective of the version from `selenium 3.0` onwards :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path to geckodriver");
```

> Geckodriver is now the default mechanism for automating Firefox. This is Mozilla's implementation of a driver for that browser, and is required for automating Firefox versions 48 and above

**Setting the path is compulsory.**

If you want to run the tests on Firefox 47 or before, set the Firefox driver capability “marionette” to false.

```
DesiredCapabilities d = new DesiredCapabilities();
d.setCapability("marionette", false);  // to disable marionette.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changelog link you mentioned is for dotnet. Here is the [Changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) for Java

> - Firefox is only fully supported at version 47.0.1 or earlier. Support   for later versions of firefox is provided by geckodriver,
>     which is   based on the evolving W3C WebDriver spec, and uses the wire
>     protocol   in that spec, which is liable to change without notice.
> - You may wish to choose an ESR release such as 45.4.0esr or earlier.
> - Firefox 47.0.0 is not supported at all.

Comment: It's mentioned that for firefox version > 47.0.1 needs geckodriver.

Comment: Firefox is only fully supported at version 47.0.1 or earlier and I am using 46.0.1 , although it's giving an exception that geckodriver needs to be set